# How to avoid mouse click on one widget triggering the signals in others in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

In my app I'm using a QTableView to show a list of images and I select some of the images by clicking left mouse button and pressing control keyboard button when I do so the app looks as the below stated image:[image]

But then when I try to use other buttons on the app like **"Destination"** and then try to select a destination folder then the app looks like this below:
[image]

Problem occurs when I click the **"select folder"** button and try to select the folder. What happens is that click on the folder selection tab, triggers QTableView widget in which I show the image and the deselects all the selected images. I want to avoid it. The way I now track the left mouse button clicks on QTableView widget is as below:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent *ev)
{
    if(obj == ui->listOfImages->viewport())
    {
        QMouseEvent * mouseEv = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev);
        if((mouseEv->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && (QApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) == true))
        {
            controlButtonCounter++;
            fetch = true;
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj,ev);
        }
        else if((mouseEv->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && (QApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::ControlModifier) == false))
        {
            if(selectedImages.size()>0)
            {
                ui->listOfImages->clearSelection();
                selectedImages.clear();
            }
            fetch = false;
            controlButtonCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj,ev);
}
```

Here `ui->listOfImages` is the QTableView widget. Other things like `controlButtonCounter` are irrelevant in taking the mouse clicks, I use it for other purposes.

Please say me how I can avoid triggering QTableView widget when I'm pressing on other things that fall in the same region as the QTableView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe it can help you:

```
void setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModality windowModality)
```

> This property holds which windows are blocked by the modal widget.
>
> This property only makes sense for windows. A modal widget prevents widgets in other windows from getting input. The value of this property controls which windows are blocked when the widget is visible. Changing this property while the window is visible has no effect; you must `hide()` the widget first, then `show()` it again.
>
> By default, this property is `Qt::NonModal`.

Comment: No, even then it's not working, the input some how reaches event function.

Comment: @the_naive, try this method 
`void setAttribute (Qt::WidgetAttribute attribute, bool on = true)`
with attribute `Qt::WA_NoMousePropagation` (or maby `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents`, `Qt::WA_NoMouseReplay`)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(obj = ui->listOfImages->viewport())
```

You are not doing a comparison there, you are assigning a value to the `obj` variable.

It should be like this:

```
if(obj == ui->listOfImages->viewport())
```

Comment: Yeah, I edited it, and I also changed it in my code, it was just the slip of my eyes and concentration, thanks for notifying though. Even rectifying this error didn't change anything.

Comment: @the_naive You should also check if the [event type](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qevent.html#type) is actually a [mouse press/release event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qevent.html#Type-enum) before casting it to a mouse event.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but from the documentation I see that it's `GraphicsSceneMousePress`, which means it's for graphics scene type object, right? Will it applicable for QTableView type of object? It might be a silly question, but I'm confused. I think I should use `MouseButtonPress`, right?

Comment: Thanks, apparently it's working. I'll come back to you if I have any further problem :).

Comment: @the_naive [`QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent`s](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#details) are only used by the graphics view framework.